# When I copy-paste JavaScript code from the site Action Nudge into Atom, it doesn't correspond?

Tags: javascript, html, css

When I type in the following code from Action Nudge to show an eBay stock list, such as below...

```
<script
  type="text/javascript"
  src="//www.auctionnudge.com/feed/item/js/theme/responsive/page/init/img_size/120/cats_output/dropdown/search_box/1/show_logo/1/lang/english/SellerID/expedite-allocations/siteid/3/MaxEntries/6">
</script>
<div id="auction-nudge-items" class="auction-nudge"></div>
```

It doesn't work in Atom (Code Software). When you close the script with an ending tag as you see within the code Action Nudge has given me, the code loses it's colour like it has become defunct, thus not registering correctly nor showing within the site when I load it. Do I need to put something above the script for it to work? I'm confused. Please help. P.s. I'm a beginner to HTML/CSS but have never used JavaScript.

Here is the whole code on the web page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewpoint" content="width=device-width">
        <meta name="description" content="Providing for your medical needs">
        <meta name="author" content="Benjamin Willis">
        <title>Expedite Allocations</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
    </head>

        <body style="background-color:white;">
            <header>
                    <div class="container">
                        <div id="branding">
                        <img width="300" height="150" src="Expedite-Logo-jpg.png" alt="Expedite Allocations" />
                    </div>
                        <nav>
                            <span><a href="Expedite Allocations Website.html">Home<a/></span>
                            <span><a href="about us.html">About Us<a/></span>
                            <span><a href="equipmentstore.html">Equipment Store<a/></span>
                            <span><a href="location.html">Location<a/></span>
                            <span><a href="contact us.html">Contact Us<a/></span>
                        </nav>
                </header>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="//www.auctionnudge.com/feed/item/js/theme/responsive/page/init/img_size/120/cats_output/dropdown/search_box/1/show_logo/1/lang/english/SellerID/expedite-allocations/siteid/3/MaxEntries/6"></script><div id="auction-nudge-items" class="auction-nudge"></div>
```

Comment: This is only a snippet of HTML, what does your whole HTML file look like? Did you include a DOCTYPE and `html` tags?

Comment: @Matthias I have edited my question to include the rest of code being the HTML. Please take a look. Would appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Oh! So it’s working for me, which was confusing me. But I was running it online, and I’m guessing you’re opening a file. You need to specificity either `http://` or `https://` before the link to the eBay script. Right now there’s just a `//`, which tells the browser to use the protocol as the page is being loaded with. When opening a file on your computer, this protocol is `file://`. So I’m guessing the browser is trying to use the file protocol to connect to eBay, which is obviously failing.

Comment: Yes that has solved it! Thank you! However... it doesn't look like how it should going off how Action Nudge have presented how the stock list would look. It's lacking the style. But I can see it has presented itself in a somewhat 'injured' form for lack of a better metaphor? Do you know why that is?